# Is Discrete Logarithm Problem reducible to Diffie Hellman Problem

Tags: number-theory

Given $g, h \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$, a solution to the Discrete Logarithm Problem finds an $x$ such that $g^x = h \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Given we have an oracle which solves Diffie-Hellmann Problem (Given $g^a, g^b  \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$, we can find $g^{ab} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ in constant time), can we solve for $x$ given $g, h \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ such that $g^x = h \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ in polynomial time?

Comment: Did you mean https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26264/can-we-reduce-diffie-hellman-problem-to-discrete-log-inversion-problem and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50587/diffie-hellman-problem-dhp-and-discrete-logarithmic-problem-dlp?

Comment: Yep! Didn't realized it was unsolved...